# Tracking for How Long an Email was Read

Tags: php, email, outlook, tracking

Greeting Overflowers,

I am asked to code an email tracker using PHP.
Email clients request my PHP script thinking it is an image (BODY's background).
However, the client (namely Outlook 2007) hangs then (showing nothing) until my PHP script reaches its timeout.

```
<?php
define("DB_FILE", "sqlite:C:\wamp\www\database.sdb");
define("QUERY", "INSERT INTO Receipt (counter_id, reader_id, start_time, end_time) VALUES (%s, \"%s\", %d, %d)");
define("TIME_OUT", "10");

function track() {
    global $counter_id;
    global $reader_id;
    global $start_time;

    $end_time = time();

    $db = new PDO(DB_FILE);
    $db->exec(sprintf(QUERY, $counter_id, $reader_id, $start_time, $end_time));
}

$counter_id = $_GET["counter_id"];
$reader_id  = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$start_time = time();

set_time_limit(TIME_OUT);
register_shutdown_function("track");

while(!connection_aborted()) {
    echo "\n";
    ob_flush();
}
?>
```

It is the loop which should keep the HTTP connection alive for the period of client's reading the tracked email.
Any thoughts on how to solve this ?

Regards

Comment: It's very unlikely you'll be able to do this. When someone views an email or goes to a web site, there is NO continues connection. There IS back and forth, but not what you're looking to do. The reason outlook hangs is because it's waiting for your "image" to appear and that's why it hits the timeout.

Comment: Yeah, please don't do this. Tell your manager or whatever that this is an awful, awful idea and really isn't right anyway.

Comment: Thank you guys, yes I agree that it is an awful idea ! Any idea how the commercial softwares (email trackers) track the time ?

Comment: I've yet to come across any analytics package that can actually track the time... and I do know most of the capabilities of my competitors in that line. The only way I can think to approach it would be using Flash or some form of client-based timer that could send a 'tick' to a server while it was running... but I'd object to any mailing that tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no sensible way of telling how long somebody has spent looking at an email.  Mail clients simply aren't designed with that kind of data gathering in mind, and trying to force a network connection to stay open will merely cause the kind of problems you've run into.

Answer (score 0):

There are people(companies) doing some simple tracking of how long an email is open by exploiting the fact that browsers will continue to request more frames for a gif (see the technique [here](https://github.com/videlalvaro/gifsockets)) until you tell them that the last frame has been sent.